# I have only a Single Activity in my Android Project and I want to show different type of Menu in different Fragment

Tags: android, menu

My Android Projects implements only **One** activity and others are all Fragments. So, for example i have 5 Fragments, I want 3 of them having a `BottomNavigation` menu while the other 2 to have `TabLayout` menu. How can i do that? I saw some people say create an `Interface` and let my `MainActivity` implement the `Interface`, then make changes to Activity from Fragment through `Interface`. Is this the best choice/practice? What other options is available and which is the best?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

**Solution 1:**

First, create a function in my `MainActivity`. Below is my project's code as an example. I modifed the layout programatically and all is written in this `showTabLayoutUI()` function.

```
fun showTabLayoutUI() {
        Log.d(TAG, "showTabLayoutUI: initiated")

        infix fun View.below(view:View) {
            var layoutParam = this.layoutParams as? RelativeLayout.LayoutParams
            layoutParam?.addRule(RelativeLayout.BELOW, view.id)
            layoutParam?.removeRule(RelativeLayout.ALIGN_PARENT_TOP)
        }
        binding.bottomNav.visibility = View.GONE //Hide Bottom Nav
        binding.sellerSiteActionBarRl.visibility = View.VISIBLE //Show Action Bar
        binding.sellerSiteTl.visibility = View.VISIBLE //Show Tab Layout

        binding.fragmentContainerView.below(binding.sellerSiteTl)
    }
```

Then in my `Fragment`, I call the method in the `MainActivity` by using this code:

```
(activity as MainActivity?)!!.showTabLayoutUI()
```

It will then hide the bottomNav and show the TabLayout.

**Solution 2:**
If Navigation Component is used, then in your `MainActivity`, you can check which Fragment is currently being displayed by typing:

```
navController.addOnDestinationChangedListener{_, destiantion, _ ->
    if(destination.id == R.id.fragmentOne) {
        //display BottomNavigation
    } else if (destination.id == R.id.fragmentTwo) {
        //display TabLayout
    }
```

Answer (score 1):

You can try to implement it using Jetpack Navigation component, it will be easier to handle.

[Check the official document](https://developer.android.com/guide/navigation/navigation-getting-started)

Comment: you mean add a menu in each fragment? I am using Navigation Component.

Comment: When you have only one activity to handle your 5 fragments using Navigation Component so, you will put the two options you need `Tab Layout` and `BottomNavigation` over each other and you can handle them with `visibility attribute` and you can achieve this `val currentFragment = NavHostFragment.findNavController(nav_host_fragment).currentDestination?.id
` get the current fragment id and check if this must show `Tab Layout` or the other one I hope it helps now

Comment: @This is done in MainActivity? Main Activity checks the `currentFragment` then change layout accordingly? Is this what you mean? But which part of MainActivity will check the currentFragment?

Comment: using the `view.Visibility` in your Fragment while creating it.

Comment: ahh ok, i think i understand now

Answer (score 1):

An interface is not necessary to handle this usecase. You can create both Views in your Activity and simply set the visibility when you create a new Fragment. `view.visibility = View.VISIBLE` `view.visibility = View.GONE`.

Comment: ahh yes, this is one of the ways i found online as well